# Allow non-zero return codes in Travis CI .yml

Tags: continuous-integration, latex, travis-ci

I am trying to setup Travis CI to build a latex report. When building the latex report some steps have to be repeated and so the first time they are called there is a non-zero return code.

My travis.yml so far is

```
language: R

before_install:
  - tlmgr install index

script:
    - latex report
    - bibtex report
    - latex report
    - latex report
    - dvipdf report.dvi report.pdf
```

However in Travis Docs it states

> If script returns a non-zero exit code, the build is failed, but continues to run before being marked as failed.

So if my first `latex report` command has a non zero return code it will fail the build.

I would only like the build to fail if the last `latex report` or `dvipdf report` failed.

Does anyone have any idea or help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `command || true` to ignore `command`'s return value.

Answer (score 2):

Just append `|| true` to your command.

(complex) Example:

```
- (docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/example:/workdir stocker-alert || true) 2>&1 | tee >(cat) | grep 'Price change within 1 day'
```

- The docker command returns < 0 (because it's a negative test), but we want to continue anyway
- `2>&1` - stderr is forwarded to stdin (to be picked up by `grep` later)
- `tee` - the output is printed (for debugging) and forwarded to grep
- Finally `grep` asserts if the output contains a required string. If not, `grep` returns > 0 failing the build.
  If we wanted to ignore `grep`s result we would need another `||true` after grep.

Taken from [schnatterer/stock-alert](https://github.com/schnatterer/stock-alert/blob/fd1fa6f9c87b874ee75bcdc5c3535b8d647d0a1e/.travis.yml).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related with your original question but I had quite the same problem.

I found a solution using [latexmk](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html). This runs latex and bibtex as many times as needed.

If you look at my Travis configuration file :

https://github.com/73VW/TechnicalReport/blob/master/.travis.yml

You will see that you simply have to add it in apt dependencies.

Then you can run it like this: `latexmk -pdf -xelatex [Your_latex_file]`